# How to record calls and store on a central server?

Tags: storage, usb-mass-storage, call-recording

Not sure if this should be asked on Software Recs Stack or not, but here goes nothing....

One of my coworkers needs to record calls whenever a call comes through on his premise cell phone. The issue is not recording the calls, instead, the issue comes from actually *storing* the calls, as the phone that is being used does not have a lot of onboard storage (i.e. has 8GB total storage).

Is there an app or some sort of configuration that we can use to store the recorded calls onto a central server, which has a lot of space? Or at the very least on a very large SD Card (i.e 64GB)?

As you would imagine, the premise cell phone deals with a lot of incoming and outgoing calls, so space is a critical concern.

Thanks for viewing!

Comment: Saving to external SD card is simple if the recording app supports. For online backup use any sync app with any cloud storage you want. With root access you can run `rclone` as a background service or scheduled job.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think YouMail (https://www.youmail.com) could *possibly* have this functionality.